# React Native OneSignal Background Notification Issue in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I followed this guide to setup the OneSignal background notification in My react native App: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/rn-android-native-module-setup-for-notification-service-extension#ios-notification-service-extension-module

Background notification is working as expected **when I installed the App directly to My device through Xcode.** But when I archive the build and install it from TestFlight, background notification doesn't work. Unless `emitNotificationEvent` event I added is not get triggered, even though the push notification is received.

When I trace the issue with Archived Build in Xcode (Using device console), noticed that `_instance` is null in `NotificationExtensionModule.m`. Anyone experienced similar issue or any idea what could be the reason ?

**Note**

- Xcode Version: 13.4
- Receiving the push notification in both instance (from test flight or direct install)
- To put a new version in TestFlight, used to increase the build number with same version number.
- Tried cleaning the build folder, re-installing the pods, nothing worked still

Adding the code snippet for further understanding of My issue:

**AppDelegate.h**

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,RCTBridgeDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```c
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  //access NotificationServiceExtensionModule emitNotificationEvent method
  [NotificationServiceExtensionModule.sharedInstance emitNotificationEvent:userInfo ];
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
```

**NotificationServiceExtensionModule.h**

```c
#import <foundation/Foundation.h>

// NotificationServiceExtensionModule.h
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

@interface NotificationServiceExtensionModule : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>

+ (NotificationServiceExtensionModule*) sharedInstance;
- (void)emitNotificationEvent:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;


@end
```

**NotificationServiceExtensionModule.m**

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// NotificationServiceExtensionModule.m
#import "NotificationServiceExtensionModule.h"

@implementation NotificationServiceExtensionModule

static NotificationServiceExtensionModule* _instance = nil;


+(NotificationServiceExtensionModule*) sharedInstance {
//    @synchronized( _instance ) {
//        if( !_instance ) {
//            _instance = [[NotificationServiceExtensionModule alloc] init];
//        }
//    }
    
    return _instance; // this returns null when installed from TestFlight. 
}

// To export a module named NotificationServiceExtensionModule
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (NSArray<NSString *> *)supportedEvents
{
  NSLog(@"Supported EVENTS__________________________");
  _instance = self;
  return @[@"NotificationEvent"];
}

- (void)emitNotificationEvent:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
  NSString *eventName = userInfo[@"custom"][@"a"];
  [self sendEventWithName:@"NotificationEvent" body:@{@"notificationPayload": eventName}];
}

@end
```

Comment: 1. What do you mean it doesn't work? 2. Share code, not screenshots 3. Are you certain that the notification has arrived to the device? You can verify this by connecting your iPhone to macOS's console and look into the logs 4. Silent notifications have `content-available:1` — without the `alert` field. However I see you trying to handle your code within `NotificationServiceExtension`. _NotificationServiceExtension_ is meant to be used for notifications ***which have alerts**. Do you have the `alert` field in your payload? 1/2

Comment: From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications): "Notification service app extensions only operate on remote notifications configured in the system to display an alert to the user. If alerts are disabled for your app, or if the payload specifies only the playing of a sound or the badging of an icon, the extension isn’t employed." 2/2

Comment: 5. last but not least, are you sure your payloads are identical? 3/2

Comment: 1. `emitNotificationEvent` I added in NotificationServiceExtensionModule doesn't trigger. But it get trigger if I install the App directly to the device. 
2. Updated the main question 
3. Yes, notification is received. It's just that `emitNotificationEvent` is not get triggered. Tried tracing the issue using logs in device console.
4. I am not using alert field in the request. 
5. What does that mean ? You mean the payload I send is unique ?

Comment: 5. I mean is the apns payload identical? Did you verify that they're identical jsons?

Comment: Yes, they are identical. JSON format is same.

Comment: 3. How did you validate notification is received?

Comment: 3. I basically trigger our OneSignal endpoint to see if I receive the push notification. Push notification receive to the device with the expected title and the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check if the app is running in the background or foreground:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  //access NotificationServiceExtensionModule emitNotificationEvent method
  [NotificationServiceExtensionModule.sharedInstance emitNotificationEvent:userInfo ];
  if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    // App was in the foreground when the notification was received
  } else {
    // App was in the background when the notification was received
  }
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
```